# why when i want to ng build --prod this problem showed?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, console, pdf-viewer

ERROR in ./node_modules/ng2-pdf-viewer/fesm5/ng2-pdf-viewer.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/src/build-optimizer/webpack-loader.js):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined
    at isAngularDecoratorMetadataExpression (E:\Mohamed Mostafa Work\new_project\reservation\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\src\transforms\scrub-file.js:265:35)
    at checkNodeForDecorators (E:\Mohamed Mostafa Work\new_project\reservation\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\src\transforms\scrub-file.js:77:21)
    at visitNodes (E:\Mohamed Mostafa Work\new_project\reservation\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16144:30)
    at Object.forEachChild (E:\Mohamed Mostafa Work\new_project\reservation\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16370:24)
    at checkNodeForDecorators (E:\Mohamed Mostafa Work\new_project\reservation\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\src\transforms\scrub-file.js:68:31)
    at visitNode (E:\Mohamed Mostafa Work\new_project\reservation\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16135:24)
    at Object.forEachChild (E:\Mohamed Mostafa Work\new_project\reservation\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16265:21)
    at checkNodeForDecorators (E:\Mohamed Mostafa Work\new_project\reservation\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\src\transforms\scrub-file.js:68:31)
    at visitNode (E:\Mohamed Mostafa Work\new_project\reservation\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16135:24)
    at Object.forEachChild (E:\Mohamed Mostafa Work\new_project\reservation\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16322:24)
    at checkNodeForDecorators (E:\Mohamed Mostafa Work\new_project\reservation\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\src\transforms\scrub-file.js:68:31)
    at visitNode (E:\Mohamed Mostafa Work\new_project\reservation\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16135:24)
    at Object.forEachChild (E:\Mohamed Mostafa Work\new_project\reservation\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16333:24)
    at checkNodeForDecorators (E:\Mohamed Mostafa Work\new_project\reservation\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\src\transforms\scrub-file.js:68:31)
    at visitNode (E:\Mohamed Mostafa Work\new_project\reservation\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16135:24)
    at Object.forEachChild (E:\Mohamed Mostafa Work\new_project\reservation\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16229:21)

Comment: GIve your sample code

Comment: When you build your project using the `--prod` flag, your app used Ahead of Time (AOT) compilation. This is the default, too, for running angular apps locally in v9. If you're using version 8 or before, running `ng serve` locally uses the Just-in-Time (JIT) compiler. Because of that, it's possible to introduce issues into your app that the JIT compiler doesn't catch so you only see the errors when you build for prod. To rule this out as the cause, simply run `ng serve --aot` to run your project locally. If it compiles, this is not the issue.

Comment: have u solved this issue? i downgraded 6  to ng2-pdf-viewer@5.3.4.. but it is not  resolved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete package-lock.json from root folder
edit package.json and change ng2-pdf-viewer version as below

```
"ng2-pdf-viewer": "5.3.4"
```

run below commands

```
npm install
npm build --prod
```

it should resolve the issue

Answer (score 6):

I got same error but finally resolved with following solution..
Unistall ng2-pdf-viewer viewer first 
then install - npm install ng2-pdf-viewer@5.3.4

Answer (score 3):

Setting the below attribute present in angular.json to false solved the problem for me:

**"buildOptimizer": false**

Answer (score 2):

After searching for a long time, this worked for me.

Upgraded @angular-devkit/build-angular to version: "~0.803.19" and then prod build worked fine. Made the following change in package.json.

```
"devDependencies": {
  "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.19",
   ...
}
```

This worked for ng2-pdf-viewer: 6.3.0 & Angular 8.3.19

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Please change your angular-devkit dependencies to latest version in the **package.josn** file:

I have changed version in below dependencies and its worked with the **--prod command**

```
"devDependencies": { "@angular-devkit/architect": "~0.803.20", "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.20", "@angular-devkit/core": "~8.3.20", "@angular-devkit/schematics": "~8.3.20", }
```

This solution working like charm :)

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to your application folder and run `npm i` command first, you seem to miss a dozen of packages

Comment: I did this and the problem still exists

Answer (score 0):

Try delete your node_modules folder and then run `npm i`

Comment: I did this and the problem still exists

Comment: Which version angular you are using?

Comment: Sometimes packages not installed / Updated due to package-lock.json. Try to delete this file from your project root folder and then npm i

Answer (score 0):

Lower version ng2-pdf-viewer work fine for me

Comment: Is this an answer or a comment?

Comment: a comment, of course. This error will not appear if you use ng2-pdf-view version 6.0.0( I have not tested for highger version yet).